# Need help understanding the contradiction in answer to if there is a rational number x such that $x^3 − x −7 = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Question:

"Is there a rational number x such that $x^3 − x −7 = 0$?"

And the textbook gives the answer:

Since $x^3 − x −7 = 0$ is equivalent to $x(x−1)(x+1) = 7$, this equation cannot be satisfied by any integer $x$, since the left-hand side is an even integer, whereas the right-hand side is not. Again, the equation cannot be satisfied by any rational number $x = m/n$, because for such an $x$ the last equation would imply that $m^3 = m(n^2) +7(n^3)$, a contradiction.

But I don't understand what the contradiction is.

Comment: For $m^3=mn^2+7n^3$, with $(man)=1$,  consider the cases (1) If $m$ is even, $n$ is odd in which case the left hand side of the equation is even  while  the right has is odd; if both $m$ and $n$ are odd, then  the right hand side is odd while the right hand side is even; similarly for $m$ odd and $n$ even,

Comment: It's a direct result of the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $ x=\frac mn$ with $n\ge 2$ and

gcd$(m,n)=1$.

the condition you wrote, which is
$$\frac{m^3}{n}=mn^2+7n^2$$

says that $\frac{m^3}{n} $ is an integer, which means that $ n$ is a divisor of $ m^3.$

$$n|m^3 \wedge (m,n)=1\implies n|m^2$$
and always by Gauss's Theorem
we get  $ n|m $ .

This contradicts the fact that they are relatively prime.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, thanks.

Comment: Thank you Hamam!

Comment: I spend my time in front of the mobile. My eyes begun to be tired. In the end they downvote under Noreason and they make loose time and points !!!

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah what do you mean? Have people been downvoting you for no reason?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Yes, everyday, i loose points WITH NO REAL REASON. I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY !?!?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I have no idea why you'd lose points. The amount of people you have helped is absolutely incredible, I am inspired by how much you help people on this site! Perhaps the downvoters are jealous of you? Whatever the reason, please don't let it get you down. Your contribution to this site is truly stupendous!

Comment: @A-levelStudent Thank you very very much. I love people like you. thanks again.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah you are most welcome!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did furrow my brow to the statement "$n$ divides $m^3$ and therefore $m$". What if $n=m^2$? It would have been better to be more clear that $(n,m)=1$ is needed here IMO

Comment: that $(n,m)=1$; $n \ge 2$  implies there is a prime $p$ that divides $n$ but not $m$, which means that same prime $p$ as it does not divide $m$, also does not divide $m^3$. Thus as there is an integer namely $p$ that divides $n$ but not $m^3$ it follows that $n$ does not divide $m^3$ and so $m^3/n$ is not an integer.

Comment: @Mike I used Gauss's Theorem.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah you gave the way through the crux of the problem, so I agree w the other comments that it is a nice answer! I do think it would have helped to be more explicit in the step I mentioned though. In any event I did give this a well-deserved upvote

Comment: @Mike Thank you Mike for the remark. I applied it.